# Default celery countdown

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

Is there a way to declare a default countdown timer in django's `settings.py` like `CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT`? It will be helpful if there is rather than just always declaring it in my class-based periodic task like?

```
try:
    ddd
except Exception as exc:
    raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

Also is it possible to have like default set of `retry=True` to all tasks?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

in django.conf

```
CELERY_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 120
CELERY_TIME_LIMIT = 240
```

Here is the celery django config docs.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Here is a list of config options.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

I was not able to find a global task retry setting but I could swear I saw it somewhere.
However, you can set retries on a per task level, you can also pass hard and soft time limits.

```
@app.task(max_retries=10, time_limit=240, soft_time_limit=120)
def task(self, auth, message):
    #do_stuff
```

Here is a list of options you can give to the celery decorator.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.retry

Comment: You did not really answer the question.. I was wondering if there is a `CELERY_RETRY_COUNTDOWN` configuration available

Comment: You're right, my apologies. I have not been able to find that option. But you can add that to the decorator `@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=30)`. I think you could also create your own Celery Task Class set it there, and then have your other tasks inherit from that one. I could provide an example if you want it.